# How to access an object attribute inside a service in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a service with a local variable object with events names:

```
    myApp.service('appService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

        var events = {
            firstEvent: "MyFirstEvent",
            secondEvent: "MySecondEvent"
        };

        this.doEvent = function(eventName)
       {           
            // do something...
       };


    }]);
```

Now I am trying to read ***events.firstEvent*** inside a controller:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'appervice', function ($scope, appService) {

var mydata = appService.events.firstEvent;

}]);
```

The problem I get this error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstEvent' of undefined
```

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S.
I also can not access the function doEvent().

Answer (score 1):

You service returns this, but you didn't put anything in there!

```
myApp.service('appService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {  
   var events = {
       firstEvent: "MyFirstEvent",
       secondEvent: "MySecondEvent"
    };
   return { events:events};
}]);
```

this will return an obeject with the events in it!

Comment: What If I'm adding function inside that service. look the edited question. How I can access that function?

Comment: got it I think: return { events:events, doEvent: this.doEvent};

Comment: 10x a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Angular executes services function when loading it, you need to return that you need from this function.

```
myApp.service('appService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    var events = {
        firstEvent: "MyFirstEvent",
        secondEvent: "MySecondEvent"
    };

    return events; 

}]);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'appervice', function ($scope, appService) {

        var mydata = appService.firstEvent;

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
function MyService($rootScope){
     var _this = {};

     _this.events = { 
         firstEvent: 'blabla1',
         secondEvent: 'blabla2'
     };
     return _this;
}

myApp.service('appService', ['$rootScope', MyService]);
```

and after that

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'appService', function ($scope, appService) {

    var mydata = appService.events.firstEvent;

}]);
```